# É possível criar paginador em uma view-component?( Asp.net MVC View-Component)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Tenho uma *view* com uma *view-component* que lista varias noticias.
Quero fazer uma paginacao dessas noticias dentro desse view-componet.
A paginacao deve ficar dentro da view-component, como faco para que esse html chame/atualize/requisite apenas o view-component novamente e como passo o parametro?

Na view a chamada da view-component é da seguinte forma:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Noticia")
```

No html da view-componente tenho:

```
@model Portal.Infra.Entidades.UltimasNoticiasViewModel
<div class="not-content">
    <h4>Últimas notícias</h4>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model.noticias)
        {
            <li>
                <span>@item.DataCriacao.ToString("dd") <br /><b class="text-capitalize">@item.DataCriacao.ToString("MMM")</b></span>
                <a href="~/noticia/index/@item.Codigo" style="color:#1e2633; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;">@item.Titulo</a>
            </li>
        }
           </ul>
</div>
```

Entao eu acrescentei o paginador:

```
@if (Model.totalItens > Model.itensPorPagina)
        {
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling( Convert.ToDecimal(Model.totalItens / Model.itensPorPagina)); i++)
                    {
                        <li class="page-item" style="display: inline;">
                            <a class="page-link" href="~/home/index/@(i+1)">@(i+1)</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </nav>
        }
```

Porém esse href é só pra eu testar os valores do paginador. Eu sei que href vai direcionar para uma outra página ou carregar a atual por inteiro, quero uma forma de clicar no item do paginador e ele recarregar apenas a view-component com na página clicada.

Comment: Você poderia editar sua pergunta colocando trecho do seu código?

Comment: Editei. É uma coisa complexa de explicar mesmo. hehehe Se nao ficou claro me avisa que tento editar novamente.